# Откуда callback получает аргументы в JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello Http');
});
```

Откуда принимаются аргументы `req` и `res`? (пример абстрактный)

Comment: так устроен движок ноды, подробнее в документации - https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: _Откуда callback получает аргументы в JS_ - От функции, которая этот callback вызывает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вас интересует то, как создавать методы, которые работают от `callback`а, то вот примерный пример:

```js
var myHttp = {
  createServer: function(callback) {
    var someMyData = {
      hoho: true,
      haha: true
    };

    callback(someMyData);
  }
}

myHttp.createServer(function(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
})
```

Также работают к примеру `Promise`. Достаточно частая практика